# How to display comma seperated list into table in EmberJS?

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js

Ok, I have Array [ "1,john", "2,jane", "3,zack" ]

At present it is displayed as [image]

I want to display as

[image]

How to to this

My code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head> 
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/3.0.1/handlebars.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember.js/1.10.0/ember.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.10.0-beta.3/ember-template-compiler.js"></script>
      <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/release/ember.debug.js"></script>
      <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/beta/ember-data.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>

      <script type="text/x-handlebars">
         {{outlet}}
      </script>


      <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">

      <table>       
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                {{#each value in App.testData}}
                <td>{{value}}</td>
            {{/each}}
            </tr>
      </table>  

      </script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
         var App = Ember.Application.create()         
        var someArray = [ {
                        'id':1,
                        'name':'john'
                    },{
                        'id':2,
                        'name':'jane'
                    },{
                        'id':3,
                        'name':'zack'
                    }];

        App.testData = someArray.map( function( el )
                    { 
                       return el.id + ',' + el.name; 
                    }); 
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: any reason you're using such an old version of Ember? If this is for a new project, I would highly recommend upgrading and also trying to recreate your issue on ember twiddle (https://ember-twiddle.com) that simulates a newer Ember 2.x / Ember-CLI environment and layout...you'll likely get a much better response. In general, you don't want slap things onto the global App variable like that and that's likely your issue....your template is getting values defined in it's automatically generated controller/view which doesn't include everything hanging off of App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `someArray` instead of `testArray` and if you have default `testArray` in your app then you have to convert it to `someArray` and set it into App
now inside `each` handlebar use `value.id` and `value.name`

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
     <head> 
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/3.0.1/handlebars.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember.js/1.10.0/ember.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.10.0-beta.3/ember-template-compiler.js"></script>
        <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/release/ember.debug.js"></script>
        <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/beta/ember-data.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>

        <script type="text/x-handlebars">
           {{outlet}}
        </script>


        <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">

        <table>       
              <tr>
                  <th>Id</th>
                  <th>Name</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  {{#each value in App.someArray}}
                  <td>{{value.id}}</td>
      <td>{{value.name}}</td>
              {{/each}}
              </tr>
        </table>  

        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
          var App = Ember.Application.create()    
          var testData =  [ "1,john", "2,jane", "3,zack" ];  
          App.someArray = testData.map(function(e){
                            var [id,name] = e.split(",");
                            return {
                              id:id,
                              name:name
                            }
                          })
        </script>
     </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: I have one more question  (can u please help) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176957/array-values-are-not-getting-reflected-while-rebinding-in-emberjs

Answer (score 1):

This should be simple by just adding html tags to break to the next line. Also make sure you wrap you handle bars property in three curly braces to make sure that handlebars knows that you are not only passing strings but also html tags. Make sure you check this tutorial on [handlebars expressions](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html) for deeper details..... I haven't tested but I hope you get the picture...

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">

      <table>
        <thead>    
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thread>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                {{#each value in App.testData}}
                <tr>{{{value}}}</tr>
               {{/each}}
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>  
      </script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
         var App = Ember.Application.create()         
        var someArray = [ {
                        'id':1,
                        'name':'john'
                    },{
                        'id':2,
                        'name':'jane'
                    },{
                        'id':3,
                        'name':'zack'
                    }];

        App.testData = someArray.map( function( el )
                    { 
           return '<td>' + el.id + '</td>' + ',' + '<td>' + el.name + '</td>'; 
                    }); 
      </script>
```

Comment: just modify my answer and I tested as well, let me know if worked for you