# Array values are not getting reflected while rebinding in EmberJS

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js

I have an array (`['Name1','Name2','Name3']`) which I am populating at page Load.
Now at button click, I want to assign some other values to that array and populate the same like

```
App.myArray = ['Name4','Name5','Name6']
```

But it is not reflected.

Complete code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>      
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/3.0.1/handlebars.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember.js/1.10.0/ember.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.10.0-beta.3/ember-template-compiler.js"></script>
      <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/release/ember.debug.js"></script>
      <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/beta/ember-data.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>

      <script type="text/x-handlebars">
         {{outlet}}
      </script>


      <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
      <button {{action "ClickFn"}}>Click Here</button>
         <ul>

            {{#each value in App.myArray}}               
               <li>{{value}}</li>
            {{/each}}
         </ul>
      </script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
         var App = Ember.Application.create()

         App.myArray = ['Name1','Name2','Name3']         

         App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

            actions: {

               ClickFn: function() {

                  App.myArray = ['Name4','Name5','Name6'] 
                  console.log(App.myArray) ;               
               }
             }
         });

      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

The current situation is

[image]

I am looking for the output should be when button click

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Ember.set` method for changes to reflect it in template. so just replace `App.myArray = ['Name4', 'Name5', 'Name6']` with the below

```
 Ember.set(App,'myArray',['Name4', 'Name5', 'Name6']);
```

I would say dont use global variable for this kind of stuff. you can introduce it in IndexRoute itself.(i guess you are doing it for testing purpose).

Answer (score 1):

`App` is an Ember object and `myArray` is its one of the property we can not set value of Ember object's property directly using `assignment` operator.
we have to use `setter` functions.

you can use Ember.set

1.`Ember.set(App,'myArray',['Name4', 'Name5', 'Name6']);`

alternatively you can also use `set` method provided by `App` object to set its property.

2. `App.set('myArray',['Name4', 'Name5', 'Name6']);`